# perl command: Append a line of text only at the first occurrence

Tags: bash, perl

I have this input file:

```
text1
match
text2
match
text3
```

I have the command that inserts a line before the match:

```
perl -lpe 'print "prepend_me" if /^match$/ && ++$i == 1' text.txt
```

And its output is:

```
text1
prepend_me
match
text2
match
text3
```

Now I would like the command that inserts a line after the match:

```
text1
match
append_me
text2
match
text3
```

How do I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use string concatenation with the default `$_` variable:

```
$ perl -lpe '$_ .= "\nappend_me" if /^match$/ && ++$i == 1' text.txt
text1
match
append_me
text2
match
text3
```

Alternatively, use `-ne` and an explicit `print`

```
perl -lne 'print; print "append_me" if /^match$/ && ++$i == 1' text.txt
```

Comment: wow, perfect! I have choice the second one because more familiar.

Comment: I don't know $_ but i just saw what I need.
What is $_?
That point after $_ . what is?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo `$_` is the *"default input and pattern-searching space"* - see the [perlvar documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar). The point is not really "after `$_`", rather it is before `=` making a *concatenation assignment operator* - see for example [What does dot-equals mean in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444284/what-does-dot-equals-mean-in-perl)

Comment: I have understand all! Thank you steeldriver. So many of the answers you gave me about perl, you almost taught me everything. XD
This point has clarified me many things:
`/^Subject:/` or `$_ =~ /^Subject:/`
and another case:
`$_ .= "\nappend_me"` or `$_ = $_ . "\nappend_me"`